# How adding custom price to download price?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I need to adding custom price with custom meta to EDD download item price.If my item price is $50 and custom price is $5 so :

The final price should be $55 which added to cart.

In getting meta and displaying it i have no problem but how can adding it to default item price for making a final price that user will pay it ?

Comment: Is this WooCommerce?

Comment: No, Easy Digital Downloads.